# AngularJS: Call a particular function before any partial page controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a particular function: `GetSession()` at the beginning of my application load. This function makes a `$http` call and get a session token: `GlobalSessionToken` from the server. This session token is then used in other controllers logic and fetch data from the server. I have call this `GetSession()`in main controller: `MasterController` in `$routeChangeStart` event but as its an asynchronous call, my code moves ahead to `CustomerController` before the `$http` response.

Here is my code:

```
var GlobalSessionToken = '';  //will get from server later 

//Define an angular module for our app 
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); 

//Define Routing for app 
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider. 
      when('/customer', { 
          templateUrl: 'partials/customer.html', 
          controller: 'CustomerController', 
          resolve: { 
            loadData: function($q){ 
                return LoadData2($q,'home'); 
            } 
          } 
      }). 
      otherwise({ 
          redirectTo: '/home'
      }); 
}]); 

//controllers start here and are defined in their each JS file 
var controllers = {}; 

//only master controller is defined in app.js, rest are in separate js files
controllers.MasterController = function($rootScope, $http){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){

        if(GlobalSessionToken == ''){
            GetSession();
        }

        console.log('START');
        $rootScope.loadingView = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(){
        console.log('ERROR');
        $rootScope.loadingView = false;
    });
};

controllers.CustomerController = function ($scope) { 
    if(GlobalSessionToken != ''){
        //do something
    }
} 

//adding the controllers to myApp angularjs app 
myApp.controller(controllers); 
//controllers end here 


function GetSession(){
    $http({
        url: GetSessionTokenWebMethod,
        method: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        GlobalSessionToken = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And my HTML has following sections:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MasterController">
    <!--Placeholder for views-->
    <div ng-view="">
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I make sure this `GetSession()` is always called at the very beginning of my application start and before any other controller calls and also called only once.

EDIT: This is how I added `run` method as per Maxim's answer. Still need to figure out a way to wait till `$http` call returns before going ahead with controllers.

```
//Some initializing code before Angular invokes controllers
myApp.run(['$rootScope','$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
   return GetSession($http, $q);
}]);

function GetSession($http, $q){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: GetSessionTokenWebMethod,
        method: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        GlobalSessionToken = data;
        defer.resolve('done');
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        defer.reject();
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't postpone the initialisation of controllers.

You may put your controller code inside a Session promise callback:

```
myApp.factory( 'session', function GetSession($http, $q){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: GetSessionTokenWebMethod,
        method: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        GlobalSessionToken = data;
        defer.resolve('done');
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        defer.reject();
    });

    return defer.promise;
} );

myApp.controller( 'ctrl', function($scope,session) {
   session.then( function() {
      //$scope.whatever ...
   } ); 
} );
```

*Alternative*: If you don't want to use such callbacks, you could have your session request synchronous, but that would be a terrible thing to do.

Comment: I had to use `session.then` instead of `Session.then`.

Answer (score 12):

Even though some of the solutions here are perfectly valid, `resolve` property of the routes definition is the way to go, in my opinion. Writing your app logic inside `session.then` in every controller is a bit too much , we're used such approach too in one of the projects and I didn't work so well.

The most effective way is to delay controller's instantiation with `resolve`, as it's a built-in solution. The only problem is that you have to add `resolve` property with similar code for every route definition, which leads to code duplication.

To solve this problem, you can modify your route definition objects in a helper function like this:

```
function withSession(routeConfig) {
  routeConfig.resolve = routeConfig.resolve || {};

  routeConfig.resolve.session = ['getSessionPromise', function(getSessionPromise) {
     return getSessionPromise();
  }]

  return routeConfig;
}
```

And then, where define your routes like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/example', withSession({
  templateUrl: 'views/example.html',
  controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
}));
```

This is one of the many solutions I've tried and liked the most since it's clean and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any details related to GetSession. For scenarios like this you should use the `resolve` property while defining your routes in `$routeProvider`. I see you are using `resolve` already.

What you can do now is to wrap the `GlobalSessionToken` into a Angular service like `GlobalSessionTokenService`and call it in the resolve to get the token before the route loads. Like

```
resolve: { 
            loadData: function($q){ 
                return LoadData2($q,'home'); 
            },
            GlobalSessionToken: function(GlobalSessionTokenService) {
                 return GlobalSessionTokenService.getToken()  //This should return promise
            }
         }
```

This can then be injected in your controller with

`controllers.MasterController = function($rootScope, $http,GlobalSessionToken){`

Comment: I have not put my MasterController in $routeProvider as my first page is customer page which I routes on first page load. So, I added the MasterController to my body tag so that it behaves live a parent controller. So, let me know how to use resolve and promise in such a case. Also see my EDIT based on Maxim's response, which works but does not wait for $http response.

Comment: And GetSession() just does a $http call to get Session Token from server (already generated on the server when user logs in).