# Redirect from app.run or root controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-promise, ngroute

I am using angularjs for a web app with asp.net mvc. Below is the code in app.js which is called in app.run() which is working fine. 
The code redirects the user to login page if the user has not logged in.
However, if the user tries to access any other page without logging in the app, angularjs first executes the code in that page and then redirects to login page. This is not an SPA hence I have not used routes. Is there anyway I can redirect the user directly from app.run() itself ?

```
function displayUserInfo() {

        $scope.userData.isUserLoggedIn = membershipService.isUserLoggedIn();

        if($scope.userData.isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            $scope.username = $rootScope.repository.loggedUser.username;
        }
        else
            if (!$location.absUrl().endsWith("ClientAdmin/Account/Login"))
               $window.location = '../Account/Login';

    }
```

Do let me know if any detail is required.

Comment: Why don't you use routes ? Is it forbidden in your project ? otherwise it would be way easier to use them.

Comment: I am not developing SPA hence did not use routes. Is there any way without defining routes?

Comment: I never went that far since I used routes myself. You should look into this subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521727/angularjs-call-a-particular-function-before-any-partial-page-controllers

Comment: Is there a way I can throw an exception in app.run() and then redirect to login page from the exception handler? Is it necessary to use routes even if you are not developing SPA?

Comment: As it's said in the link I gave you, you can put the code logic you don't want to trigger in a session condition. In your run(), you instantiate a session variable, so this way if you didn't went through run() before, you won't trigger your unwanted code.